# c protobuf data can‘t deserialize/unpack？

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

I have wrote some c code referenced by https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c/wiki/Examples

```
Operation msg = OPERATION__INIT;
uint8_t *buf;
unsigned len;
msg.operation = "d";
msg.tracking_id = 1;
msg.x = 0.22556;
msg.y = 0.65110;
len = operation__get_packed_size(&msg);
buf = malloc(len);
operation__pack(&msg, buf);
fprintf(stderr,"Writing %d serialized bytes\n", len);

Operation *msg1 = operation__unpack(NULL, len, buf);
printf("operation:%s\n", msg1->operation);
printf("%d\n", msg1->tracking_id);
printf("%f\n", msg1->x);
printf("%f\n", msg1->y);
```

the print result is below:

```
Writing 3 serialized bytes
operation:d
0
0.000000
0.000000
```

why the `tracking_id`, `x` and `y` is zero? Is there something wrong with my code?

the Operation definition is below:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Operation {
    required string operation = 1;
    optional int32 tracking_id = 2;
    optional double x = 3;
    optional double y = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tracking_id`, `x` and `y` are `optional`, so you need to specify whether they are provided or not.

According to the page you linked, you need to add the following:

```
msg.has_tracking_id = 1;
msg.has_x = 1;
msg.has_y = 1;
```

Similarly, the receiver needs to check if the values were provided.

```
if (msg1->has_tracking_id)
    printf("%d\n", msg1->tracking_id);
if (msg1->has_x)
    printf("%f\n", msg1->x);
if (msg1->has_y)
    printf("%f\n", msg1->y);
```

Don't forget to free to the buffer.

```
amessage__free_unpacked(msg1, NULL);
```